# Issue using render props to create toggle button to show/hide child components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Using below Original HTML I would like to show/hide a couple child components based on a toggle click. The issue I am having is the EditToggle link needs to show next to the h2 (inside "subtitle-container") but the two components need to render below (outside of "subtitle-container").

When using the EditToggle on the Proposed Component I have to put the two components inside of the render function so they can see the editing value. This does not work since they now render inside of the "subtitle-container" div. How can I modify these components so I can use the EditToggle as a render prop but still have the two child components render outside of "subtitle-container" in the html?

Optional notes: The original section HTML is duplicated many times on a larger parent component that is not shown. Given this this is one of the reasons why I  extracted the state controlling the toggle into its own component using render props.

Also, the save in the EditComponent will return the ReadOnlyComponent but the inner workings of the Edit/Read are not shown here as they are not the concern.

Thanks!

*Original HTML*

```
<div class="section" id="section-one">
  <div class="subtitle-container">
    <h2 class="subtitle">Title</h2>
    <a href="">Toggle</a>
  </div>
  <!-- ReadOnlyComponent -->
  <!-- EditComponent -->
</div>
```

*Proposed React Component*

```
export class SectionComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="section" id="section-one">
        <div className="subtitle-container">
          <h2 className="subtitle">Title</h2>
            <EditToggle
              render={(editing) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment>
                  {editing ? <ReadOnlyComponent /> : EditComponent }
                </React.Fragment>
              )
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*Proposed toggle link component using render props*

```
export class EditToggle extends React.Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    editing: false,
  };

  onToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
        editing: !this.state.editing,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a onClick={this.onToggle}></a>
        {this.props.render(this.state.editing)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The base idea here, I believe, is a portal https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

So what we can do is:

```
export class SectionComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="section" id="section-one">
        <div className="subtitle-container">
          <h2 className="subtitle">Title</h2>
            <EditToggle
              portalEl={this.portal}
              render={(editing) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment>
                  {editing ? <ReadOnlyComponent /> : EditComponent }
                </React.Fragment>
              )
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div ref={(ref)=> this.portal=ref}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
export class EditToggle extends React.Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    editing: false,
  };

  onToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
        editing: !this.state.editing,
    });
  }
  renderPortal(){
    if(this.props.portalEl){
        return ReactDom.createPortal(this.props.render(this.state.editing), this.props.portalEl)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a onClick={this.onToggle}></a>
        {this.renderPortal()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```